# Postgresql - Create multicolumn Index - statistics created or not

Tags: postgresql, statistics

In Mssql, when we create multi column index, it itself creates multicolumn stats on those columns.

In postgresql, are multicolumn stats created or not

Answer (score 0):

Creating a multi-column index does not automatically create cross-column statistics in PostgreSQL. You have to create extended statistics explicitly with [`CREATE STATISTICS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html):

```
CREATE STATISTICS stats_name ON col1, col2, col3 FROM tab;
```

Also, PostgreSQL does not trigger statistics collection when you create an index or extended statistics, so it is a good idea to explicitly calculate statistics on the table afterwards:

```
ANALYZE tab;
```

In PostgreSQL, the performance of the optimizer is crucial, since query plans are only cached in special cases. As a consequence, you should only incur the overhead of extended statistics if you know that you need them.